# How can the variables set using apigee-access be used in express in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, apigee

How can the variables set using apigee-access be used in express?

I am trying to get a variable using apigee-access like this:

```
 http.createServer(function(req, resp) {
  var userId= apigee.getVariable(req,username);   
  resp.end('Hello, World!\n'+userId+' Error:'+err);    
  });
```

and the  trying to use the variable userId in

```
app.post('/employees', function(req, res) {
if (!req.is('json')) {
    res.jsonp(400, {
        error : 'Bad request'
    });
    return;
}



var b = req.body;
var e = {
    'userName' : userId,

    'displayName' : userId+"_details",
    'phone' : b.phone
};

createEmployee(e, req, res);
```

});

I am getting an error ReferenceError: "userId" is not defined. while executing the same . Is there a way to access this variable?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `userId` as a local variable in the scope of the `createServer` function. By the time the server callback is fired and userId is defined, your `e` setter code has already been executed.

I imagine it works in the `resp.end` though right? It writes it to the page? You'll need to devise a more "node-like" way of handling the userId that doesn't require storing the userId as a global variable (that would be VERY bad) or even storing it in code at all. I'd recommend using a route path and require the end user to specify the userId when making a POST:

```
app.post('/employees/:userId', function(req, res) {
    // req.params.userId can now be used
    if (!req.is('json')) {
        res.jsonp(400, {
            error: 'Bad request'
        });
        return;
    }

    var body = {
        userName: req.params.userId,
        displayName: req.params.userId+"_details",
        phone: req.body.phone
    };

    // now you're probably going to do something with 'body'
});
```